# Recorrer el resultado de una select en postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estoy intentando realizar una función, para recorrer el resultado de una select y con el id que devuelve, llamar a otra funccion.

la funcion donde estoy haciendo la select es la siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_code_references()
RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    cliente RECORD;
    query_client text;

BEGIN
    query_client := 'SELECT idcliente INTO idcliente FROM m_clientes WHERE deleted=False';
        FOR cliente IN EXECUTE query_client LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE '-- CLIENTE: %', cliente.idcliente;
        select public.encode_references(cliente.idcliente);
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$;
```

La select devuelve 2 o mas filas y luego quiero recorrer el resultado y con el id, llamar a otra funcion pasandolo como parametro.

Pero me sale el siguiente error: no se puede abrir como cursor.

Si me podeis ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes quitar el "INTO idcliente" de la query, no tiene sentido ahí, pues ya el retorna el valor en idcliente

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_code_references()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
COST 100
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF 
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
cliente RECORD;
query_client text;

BEGIN
query_client := 'SELECT idcliente  FROM m_clientes WHERE deleted=False';
    FOR cliente IN EXECUTE query_client LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE '-- CLIENTE: %', cliente.idcliente;
    PERFORM public.encode_references(cliente.idcliente);
END LOOP

 Return new;

  END;
  $BODY$;
```

Comment: Esto lo he probado y me devuelve el siguiente error:
NOTICE:  -- CLIENTE: 0
NOTICE:  -- idcliente: _idcliente
ERROR:  la consulta no tiene un destino para los datos de resultado
HINT:  Si quiere descartar los resultados de un SELECT, utilice PERFORM.
CONTEXT:  función PL/pgSQL update_codes_by_change_variety() en la línea 10 en sentencia SQL
SQL state: 42601

Comment: entonces se debe ejecutar un PERFORM de la llamada a la funcion encode_references, edité la respuesta para que veas

Comment: Ya lo solucione, me faltaba lo que acabas de poner y tambien retornar el new. Si quieres pon el return new y doy como valida tu respuesta.

Comment: Listo con el return new, los triggers siempre llevan return new, old o null. Pero siempre deben retornar algo :-D

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya he validado tu respuesta